# Angular Meteor (blaze #if and ui-view)

Tags: angular-meteor

```
  {{#if currentUser}}
    <div ng-app="appy">
      <a href="/home">Home</a>
      <a href="/page">Page</a>
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    Here will be logIn page
  {{/if}}
```

Goal is to render menu and content only to logged users, if not logged render  login page. problem is {{#if currentUser}} makes my ui-view element to not render templates it shuld.

How to repair it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div ng-app="appy">
  <div ng-show="$root.currentUser">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    <a href="/page">Page</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="$root.currentUser">
    Here will be logIn page
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-show is still rendering html elements. dont like it.

Comment: The html elements render here because it's not running angular. Try it in your own app and it will work like you want.